# Idiom to indicate accepting culpability for an action

Tags: idioms

Is there any idiom which resembles similar meaning to **as you make your bed so you must lie in it** (one must accept the bad results of his action)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://english.stackexchange.com/q/276100/385236 or https://english.stackexchange.com/a/175018/385236